# How do you obtain the zero inflation parameter (pz) of a zero-inflated NB model using glmmADMB?

Tags: r

I have run a zero-inflated negative binomial model using the glmmADMB package in R. From what I understand, the pz parameter is the zero-inflation parameter and it is fitted by the package to the model that you run- the pz value that best fits your data is searched for and the package starts searching from pz=0.2. This is the default and can be changed.

After you run the model, does anyone know how to find what pz value is chosen for the data?

Answer (score 0):

The zero-inflation estimate can be obtained (along with its standard deviation) from the model object. See below using built-in data from the `glmmADMB` package:

```
library(glmmADMB)
# munge data
Owls = transform(Owls, Nest = reorder(Nest, NegPerChick), 
                 logBroodSize = log(BroodSize), NCalls = SiblingNegotiation)
# fit model
fit_zinb = glmmadmb(NCalls ~ (FoodTreatment + ArrivalTime) * SexParent +
                             offset(logBroodSize) + (1 | Nest), 
                    data = Owls, zeroInflation = TRUE, 
                    family = "nbinom")
# overall summary, check for match
summary(fit_zinb)
# zero-inflation estimate
fit_zinb$pz
# zero-inflation standard deviation
fit_zinb$sd_pz
```